# Why does my website look TERRIBLE only on the iPhone 7 Plus and the iPhone 12 Pro Max?

Tags: css, media-queries

**WHAT IS THE ISSUE?**

- When I visit my website on the iPhone 7 Plus and the iPhone 12 Pro max, the hero image is zoomed, the text is enormous and the navigation bar is missing.
- When I visit my website on seemingly every other mobile phone, the hero image is the correct size, the text is the correct size, and the mobile navigation bar is visible.
- Shockingly, when the problematic phones are turned sideways and set their zoom to 50%, they look EXACTLY like the laptop version of my website! [iPhone 7 Plus, 50% zoom, orientation: landscape].

I got this horrific mess of a UI with this exact HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Multiversity -- Find your University</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../stylesheets/navbar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../stylesheets/general.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../stylesheets/hero.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../stylesheets/footer.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../stylesheets/colour-palette.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../stylesheets/cursors.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:ital,wght@0,400;0,700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="../pagetab-icons/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="../pagetab-icons/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="../pagetab-icons/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="../pagetab-icons/site.webmanifest">
    <link rel="preload" href="../images/hero-img-laptops.jpg" as="image" media="(min-width: 1201px)">
    <link rel="preload" href="../logo/multiversity-logo.png" as="image">
    <link rel="preload" href="../images/hero-img--phones-xs.jpg" as="image" media="(max-width: 500px)">
    <link rel="preload" href="../images/hero-img--phones.png" as="image" media="(min-width: 501px) and (max-width: 768px)" >
    <link rel="preload" href="../images/hero-img--tablets.jpg" as="image" media="(min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1200px)">
  </head>
  <body class="normal-cursor--field">
    <section class="hero-section normal-cursor--field">
      <p class="slogan normal-cursor--field">
        <span id="slogan--1">for students, </span>
        <span id="slogan--2">by&nbsp;students</span>
      </p>
      <a href="/search" class="normal-cursor--field">
        <button class="hero-search-bar pointer-cursor--field">
          <div>
            <span class="search-bar-label pointer-cursor--field">Click here: find a university</span>
            <span class="search-bar-cursor"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="search-icon--container"><img class="search-icon" src="../icons/search.svg"></div>
        </button>
      </a>
      <a class="add-scholarship--link pointer-cursor-small--field" href="/universities">
        OR ADD YOUR UNIVERSITY
      </a>
    </section>
    <script async src="../js/utils.frontend.js" type="module"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

and this exact CSS (for the main file)

```
/* 
TOWARDS THE END, GIVE EVERY FONT A BACKUP FONT!!!

*/

:root {
  --hero-link-gradient: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(72, 123, 190), rgb(255, 255, 255)),
  linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1), rgb(118, 88, 230), rgba(0, 100, 200, 1));
  --hero-font-size: 7em;
}

/* What the user is met with when they click on the page */
.hero-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 50px;
  background-image: url(../images/hero-img-laptops.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 3%;
  color: white;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /* background-color: var(--homepage-main-colour); */
  height: 97.5vh; 
}

/* All the children of the hero section are given styles */
.hero-section > * {
  /* Unnecessary code? */
  /* display: block; */
  cursor: default;
  font-family: var(--main-font);
}

#slogan--1, #slogan--2 {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: var(--hero-font-size);
}

.hero-search-bar {
  /* Necessary to add in the font AGAIN */
  font-family: var(--tertiary-font);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: left;
  width: 20em;
  max-width: 75vw;
  margin-top: 4vh;
  margin-bottom: 1vh;
  padding: 0.25em 0.6em;
  padding-bottom: 0.3em;
  border-radius: 1.8rem;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: white;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #7e7e7e;
  background-color: white;
}

.search-bar-label {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.hero-search-bar:active {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.search-bar-cursor {
  animation: blink 1.7s infinite;
  background-color: #414141;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0.68em;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 2px;
}

@keyframes blink {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}  

.search-icon--container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 1.5em;
}

.search-icon {
  height: 85%;
}


.add-scholarship--link {
  margin-top: 0.3em;
  padding-bottom: 0.2em;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: var(--tertiary-font);
  background: var(--hero-link-gradient);
  background-size: 100% 0.1em, 0 0.1em;
  background-position: 100% 100%, 0 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: background-size 400ms;
}

.add-scholarship--link:hover {
  background-size: 0 0.1em, 100% 0.1em;
}


/*     MEDIA QUERIES    */
/* -------------------- */

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .hero-section {
    background-image: url(../images/hero-img--tablets.jpg);
    background-position: 17%;
  }

  #slogan--1, #slogan--2 {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

  .hero-section {
    background-image: url(../images/hero-img--phones.png);
    background-position: bottom center;
  }

  #slogan--1, #slogan--2 {
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    font-size: calc(var(--hero-font-size) - 3em);
  }

  .hero-search-bar {
    width: 14em;
    z-index: 5;
  }

  
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

  .add-scholarship--link {
    font-size: 1.1em;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {

  .hero-section {
    background-image: url(../images/hero-img--phones-xs.jpg);
    background-position: bottom center;
  }

  /* Setting the style for the hamburger menu to be visible with the new image*/
  .hamburger-menu .line {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px black;
  }

  .slogan {
    display: flex;
    line-height: 6em;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 95vw;
  }

  .hero-search-bar {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 19px;
  }

  .add-scholarship--link {
    font-size: 1em;
  }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .slogan {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .slogan {
    font-size: 10px;
  }

  .hero-search-bar {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
  }

}
```

**WHAT HAVE I ALREADY TRIED?**

- I tried writing media queries targeting devices by device pixel ratio so I could style them separately, but nothing changed. What I found was that the devices aren't being matched by ANY of my media queries - even when I set a media query that effectively applies to all devices (min-resolution: 1dpi)!
- I tried using different browsers, clearing cache, un-linking all stylesheets one by one to find a problematic one, even un-linking the JavaScript file - but nothing changed. It still looked the same.
- I connected my iPhone 7 Plus to a MacBook and inspected the website via the Develop menu. I found out that the UserAgent is being correctly transmitted to my site, the correct image for it is being preloaded by my HTML file (even though that image is not being displayed - it's displaying the laptop version). I found out that window.innerWidth has the width I've been expecting (414 px).